# Phonegap - Best way to support multiple resolutions

Tags: android, css, cordova

I'm creating an app with PhoneGap, and would like to target multiple Android devices.
The problem is that on the documentation I see there are many ways to do this, and I would like to know the right one.

On the Android docs I see that I can use a different CSS for every screen density, but then I would need to create 4 css for every app I do.
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html

On Google I found that I should use responsive layout, but a friend told me that it's not the right thing to do.

What's the best way to create an app in PhoneGap without creating many unnecessary CSS files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Phonegap, I would use a mobile framework, like jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch, etc. These frameworks handle this for you, and enable responsive layout.  Your friend's opinion seems a bit unfounded.  I'm using jQuery Mobile and it has worked on every mobile device I've tested on: Galaxy Nexus, iPod touch, iPad, and Kindle. My app is very large and complex, and no where in my code do I zig or zag based on screen size. I have a single CSS file, and it supports several themes as well.

Comment: That's all good for the other things, but what about images, will I have to provide different resolution images (as we do in Android), or i'll have to take one large image and scale it down for the low density screens.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely recommend creating a responsive layout.  Use a mobile first technique to target the smallest screen size, then use media queries to target larger screen sizes.  Every phone behaves a little differently, expect some differences.